# Using find starts with multiple selector ignoring case

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using JQuery 1.10.2, and I'm trying to find all the link starts with multiple selector, I'm sure that it can be optimized, but I don't know how.

The selector must return all the link that starts with these urls :

```
/GalleryDetail.aspx
/gallerydetail.aspx
GalleryDetail.aspx 
gallerydetail.aspx 
/sketchbook.aspx
/SketchBook.aspx
SketchBook.aspx
sketchbook.aspx
```

at this moment, I'm using this :

```
valNow.find("a[href^='/GalleryDetail.aspx'], a[href^='/gallerydetail.aspx'], a[href^='GalleryDetail.aspx'], a[href^='gallerydetail.aspx'],
a[href^='/sketchbook.aspx'], a[href^='/SketchBook.aspx'],
a[href^='sketchbook.aspx'], a[href^='SketchBook.aspx']");
```

I searched, and I read that I can use filter, but since this is multiple  selector, I don't even know where to start. And also I thought I can use this to do the ignorecase.

```
valNow.find("a[href^='/[gG]allery[dD]etail.aspx']")
```

but somehow it doesn't return the link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

```js
$("a").filter((_, el) => {
        var startsWith = ["/gall", "sketch"],  // values to look for
            href = (el.getAttribute("href") || "").toLowerCase();  // the href value as defined in the markup
  
        return startsWith.some((val) => href.indexOf(val) == 0);   // returns true if the current elements (<el>) href attribute starts with (== 0) any of the values in <startsWith>
//      return startsWith.some((val) => href.indexOf(val) == 0 || href.indexOf("/" + val) == 0)
      })
      .addClass("foo");
```

```css
.foo { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/GalleryDetail.aspx">/GalleryDetail.aspx</a>
<a href="/gallerydetail.aspx">/gallerydetail.aspx</a>
<a href="GalleryDetail.aspx">GalleryDetail.aspx</a>
<a href="gallerydetail.aspx">gallerydetail.aspx</a>
<a href="/SketchBook.aspx">/SketchBook.aspx</a>
<a href="/sketchbook.aspx">/sketchbook.aspx</a>
<a href="SketchBook.aspx">SketchBook.aspx</a>
<a href="sketchbook.aspx">sketchbook.aspx</a>
```

Comment: Thank you andreas, is it possible that it will also pick up without the slash in front of it, or should i use `startsWith = ["/gall", "gall", "/sketch", "sketch"]`

Comment: Strictly speaking this wouldn't be "starts with" anymore but a "maybe starts with" but it sure is possible :) I've added an alternative in the code (the commented second return) which looks for `<val>` and `/<val>`. With this change the `startsWith` array could be reduced to `["gall", "sketch"]`. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h04cdwd7/) is a fiddle with the change.